# Flutter on browser, detect device

Tags: android, ios, flutter, detect

I am running a Flutter web only app.

I need to know the device on which the browser is. How do I achieve this?

`Platform.isAndroid` nor `Platform.isIOS` does not work in the browser, since it is not an Android nor ios app.

kIsWeb will not work either, because it will always be web, so I am stuck.

Thank you